# Magento Magmi import and caching issue

Tags: magento, magmi

Who can help - I am importing simple products into Magento 1.9.x using Magmi. Is it correct that cache is not deleted after import? And is there a way to flush only caches (product caches, full page cache) related to the imported products?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to delete the cache, just flush it by the following code- 
Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->flush();

And, after flushing it reindex your data by-

$indexingelement = array("cataloginventory_stock","catalog_product_attribute", ,"catalog_category_flat", "groupscatalog2_category","catalog_product_attribute","catalogsearch_fulltext","catalog_product_flat","catalog_product_price","catalog_url","catalog_category_product","groupscatalog2_product", "tag_summary");

//reindex
foreach ($indexingelement as $indexing) 
{
    echo $indexing.' is Reindexed'.'
';
    try 
    {
    $process = Mage::getModel('index/indexer')->getProcessByCode($indexing);
    $process->reindexAll();
    } 
    catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'Error occured while reindexing' . $indexing . '
';
    print($set->getMessage());
    }

Comment: Flushing the cache means deleting the cache. So everything needs to be rebuilded....